# Numerically integrating the same SPDE on different dimensions results in different outcomes

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, stochastic-pde, stochastic-approximation

Let us consider a general SPDE of the form 
$$\partial_t h = F(h, \partial_x h, (\partial_x h)^2, \partial_x^2 h,..) + \eta,$$
where $\eta$ is a normal random variable in space and time with 
$$<\eta(x,t) \eta(x', t')> = 2D \delta(x-x')\delta(t-t').$$

If I integrate this SPDE in time over $[0s,500s]\times[1m,2^{14}m]$, and analyze the resulting function $h(x,t=500s)$, I see that $h(x,t=500s)$ has some interesting properties, which are irrelavent right now.

However, if I integrate the same SPDE over $x$ on the same domain, the resulting function $h(x,t=500s)$ is quite different from what I had obtained before.

**Question:**

Considering the fact that I'm numerically integrating the same SPDE, but just along different dimensions, I cannot understand why the resulting functions, namely $h(x,t=500s)$, are different, so why am I getting different results in these cases?

Comment: What are the boundary and initial conditions?

Comment: @user721481 $h_(x,t=0) = 0$ and no boundary conditions (the actual SPDE I'm considering is ill-posed, but that does not matter for the sake of this question; If you like you can add a boundary condition as well)

Comment: maybe that is why you are getting different results. you integrate with different initial conditions ( and possibly different noise values)